# separate fields by comma using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How do I place commas between fields?

Input data

```
12123 'QA test case 1' 'QA environment'   
12234 'UAT test case 1' 'UAT environment'
```

Expected output

```
12123, 'QA test case 1', 'QA environment'   
12234, 'UAT test case 1', 'UAT environment'
```

Comment: You might want to review the help article on [ask] for advice on how to ask a good question.

Comment: The hard part in bash isn't adding the commas. The hard part is splitting into fields when you have optional quotes around fields.

Comment: I have tried with this code but not working...awk -v q="," '{ f1=$1; $1=""; print f1, q substr($0,2) q}' input.dat>> output.dat

Comment: @user3347931 It's good that you respond with the description of what you tried, but this information belongs in the question body itself, not comments (you can [edit] the question). Also, your command is not in pure bash, but the question implies that a bash solution is needed. If using `awk` and other tools is acceptable, you can add tags for relevant tools to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this awk:

```
awk -F" '" '{ print $1, $2, $3 }' OFS=", '" data
```

or using a `BEGIN` block:

```
awk -F" '" 'BEGIN {OFS="," FS} { print $1, $2, $3 }' data
```

In either case, the `FS` is being set to `'` (space + "'") and `OFS` is being set to "," + `'`.  It's based on the assumption `'` is a validly unique field separator and all input data is formatted/arranged as in the question.

Comment: I've answered in `awk` because of this duplicate question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/23964305/1259917

Comment: Works fine with the sample data, but just to note the constraints: solution is limited to 3 fields and will also not work if the 2nd and/or 3rd fields are unquoted.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a CSV parser:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne '
  puts CSV.generate_line(
         CSV.parse_line($_.strip, {:col_sep => " ", :quote_char => "'\''"}
       ), {:force_quotes => 1}) 
'  file
```

```
"12123","QA test case 1","QA environment"
"12234","UAT test case 1","UAT environment"
```

Comment: +1; assuming that the deviations from the OP's requested format are acceptable - switch to double-quoting, ALL fields quoted, no space after comma - this bona-fide CSV solution is (a) generic (works with any number of fields), (b) more secure than the [`eval`-based solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23964163/45375) and (c) superior to the [pure bash solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23964128/45375) in that it doesn't normalize (and thus potentially alter) field-_interior_ whitespace.

Comment: This one's best. The OP just has to consider if `$_.strip` should be `$_.rstrip` instead; and if `generate_line` should have the option `:col_sep => ", "`. `parse_line` could also have `:skip_blanks => true`.

Answer (score 2):

A naïve `bash` implementation that assumes that no (escaped) `'` instances ever appear *inside* a field:

- Original single-quoting is preserved.
- Accepts any number of input fields.
- Any fields may be single-quoted.
- *Caveat*: whitespace between fields is normalized (replaced with a single space each), as is whitespace *inside* a quoted field.

Input is assumed to come from file `file`:

```bsh
# Read all whitespace-separated tokens (potentially across quoted field boundaries).
while read -ra tkns; do  
  # Initialize per-line variables.
  numTkns=${#tkns[@]} i=0 inField=0
  # Loop over all tokens.
  for tkn in "${tkns[@]}"; do
    # Determine if we're inside a quoted field.
    [[ $tkn == \'* ]] && inField=1
    [[ $tkn == *\' ]] && inField=0
    # Determine the output separator:
    if (( ++i == numTkns )); then
      sep=$'\n' # last token, terminate output line with \n
    else
      # inside a field: use just a space; between fields: use ', '
      (( inField )) && sep=' ' || sep=', '
    fi
    # Output token and separator.
    printf '%s%s' "$tkn" "$sep"
  done
done < file
```

Answer (score 2):

Your input data looks very much like an argument list. Therefore, one convenient approach would be to define a bash function that simply returns its argument list as comma separated tokens and invoke that for each line in your file.

However, the simple implementation below will lose the quotes around the multi-word tokens (but it will place the commas properly). If you need those quotes exactly as they were, it would get a bit more complicated (it's very easy to output every token quoted though):

```
#!/bin/bash
function csv_args() {
    while [ -n "$1" ]; do
        echo -n "$1"
        shift
        [ -n "$1" ] && echo -n ', '
    done
    echo
}

while read line; do
    eval csv_args $line
done < /path/to/your/file
```

Comment: I had much the same thoughts before I saw your answer. I came up with this: `while IFS= read -r line; do eval set -- $line; (IFS=,; echo "$*"); done < file` -- With this use of eval, we're **really** hoping there's nothing malicious in that file.

Comment: @glennjackman: Security issues aside: not only will this not preserve quoting, it will also not place a space after each comma.

Comment: Seductively simple, but - `eval` security issues aside - since preserving the original quoting is not an option, I suggest defaulting to quoting _everything_ (`echo -n "'$1'"`), because I think it's fair to assume that the original quoting served a purpose.

Comment: @glennjackman: Here's an all-fields-quoted alternative that also inserts the space after each comma: `while IFS= read -r line; do eval set -- $line; o=$(printf "'%s', " "$@"); o=${o%, }; echo "$o"; done < file`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed "s/ '/,&/g" file
12123, 'QA test case 1', 'QA environment'
12234, 'UAT test case 1', 'UAT environment'
```

Comment: This fails with a line like this `12123 'QA test case 1' 'QA environment' some more` and gives `12123, 'QA test case 1', 'QA environment' some more`, missing a comma here: `, some, more`.  Se example in my post.

Comment: You might be right, or not. Until the OP tells us if that input can occur and, of so, what it means, we're just guessing. This and the script you posted will probably "fail" if there are newlines inside the quoted fields or escaped quotes inside the fields or.... but there's no point guessing about what the desired output would be for input that may not exist in the OPs actual input data. If the OPs input data looks like he posted, this trivial sed script will work just fine. If it could be different then he needs to provide more info.

Comment: It's not a generic solution. You do assume that all other than the first field starts with space `'`. For the input above its OK, same with the solution posted by `n0741337`

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely correct. I don't think any solution posted here is a generic solution, they would all produce results that are probably undesirable for some types of input other than what was shown in the sample but common in quoted CSV files, say. The question is - how much do you want to assume about what else MIGHT be in the OPs actual input and what MIGHT the OP want done with it if present. I chose to just post the simplest possible solution for the actual posted data and leave it up to the OP to tell us if (s)he has anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I handle `csv` with `awk`

```
cat file
12123 'QA test case 1' 'QA environment' some more
12234 'UAT test case 1' 'UAT environment'
```

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {if ($i~t) c++;printf "%s"(c%2?FS:", "),$i}print $NF}' t=\' file
12123, 'QA test case 1', 'QA environment', some, more
12234, 'UAT test case 1', 'UAT environment'
```

This keep track of how many  `'` it finds.
If its `0 2 4 6 etc` you are outside a group, split using `,`
If its `1 3 5 7 etc` you are inside a group, split by  (a space)

---

Since you now have a good separator, you can get rid of the  `'`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {if ($i~t) c++;sub(t,"",$i);printf "%s"(c%2?FS:","),$i}sub(t,"",$NF);print $NF}' t=\' file
12123,QA test case 1,QA environment,some,more
12234,UAT test case 1,UAT environment
```

---

You could also use `FPAT` that is used to define fields, opposed to `FS` that define separators, but then you need `gnu awk` 4.x, and it would not be portable.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf "%s, ",$i;print $NF}' FPAT="[^' ]+|'[^']+'" file
12123, 'QA test case 1', 'QA environment', some, more
12234, 'UAT test case 1', 'UAT environment'
```

How does the `FPAT="[^' ]+|'[^']+'"` works?
1. A field should not contain one or more `'` or space. `[^' ]+` eks `some` and `more`
2. A field starts with `'` then one or more not `'` and then ends with `'`. `'[^']+'` eks `'test data'`

Comment: You would find that it would be more efficient to not depend on field separators, etc. even if the code would seem smaller.

Comment: @konsolebox I am not sure what you mean. Can you give some example on how to solve this without looking at field by field?

Comment: I actually meant 'would not seem smaller' before sorry. Anyway I mean not depending on the features of the tool to separate tokens by its own and that is walking character by character instead of trying to refine an output from those features (e.g. word splitters). An example script: http://sourceforge.net/p/playshell/code/ci/master/tree/source/utils/parawrap.sh. This thing is easy to solve but I'm not in a mood to contribute a code when the OP hasn't done anything. At least not today.

Answer (score 0):

This solution (I believe) is not very nice, but standard at least:

```
awk 'BEGIN{SP="[:space:]"}{gsub("(["SP"]*('\''[^'\'']*'\''|[^'\''"SP"])+)","&,");if(match($0, (",["SP"]+$")))$0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)substr($0,RSTART+1)}1'
```

Though some "broken" awk implementations don't support character classes with the [[:foo:]] style, in that case you can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{SP=" \t\f\v\r\n"}{gsub("(["SP"]*('\''[^'\'']*'\''|[^'\''"SP"])+)","&,");if(match($0, (",["SP"]+$")))$0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)substr($0,RSTART+1)}1'
```

Note: I used '\'' to place each single quote character because that's a simple and standard way to do it. If you want to use this line in a ".awk" file, just replace every occurrence with a single quote.