# How to place comma between fields with single quote using awk

Tags: awk

I have tried with following awk but it didn't work as expected.

```
awk -v q="," '{ f1=$1; $1=""; print f1, q substr($0,2) q}' input.dat > output.dat
```

Input data

```
12123 'QA test case 1' 'QA environment'   
12234 'UAT test case 1' 'UAT environment'
```

Expected output

```
12123, 'QA test case 1', 'QA environment'   
12234, 'UAT test case 1', 'UAT environment'
```

Comment: Within the `print` statement, use quotes around the comma you want to insert: `print f1", "q ...`

Comment: Please don't create _multiple_ questions for what is essentially a _single_ one: your original question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23963648/45375, has received answers. If they don't work for you, provide feedback.